# changing a url dynamically in groovy

Tags: groovy

I have been trying to figure this problem out for quite a while.

I would like to change every occurrence of a url within a string like so:

```
    int i = 0
    string.for each occurrence of ("/some static part/" + ${this could be anything}) {

    replace with "/some other static part" + i + "/some other static part/"

    i++
    }
```

Thats is the best way i can describe it.

I cannot use a replaceAll because the end part of the url does change and the url to change it to also changes.

any ideas?

Comment: Can you think of a better way to describe it?  Maybe an example or three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def searchStatic = 'first static part'
def dynamicPart = 'some dynamic part'
def pattern = "${searchStatic}${dynamicPart}"

def replaceStatic1 = 'first static bit of replacement'
def replaceStatic2 = 'second static bit of replacement'

def idx = 0
url = url.replaceAll(pattern) { replaceStatic1 + idx++ + replaceStatic2 }
```

Not the most elegant or concise, but it accomplished what I believe your question is asking.

Answer (score 1):

Groovy templates are just what you are looking for:

```
def url='someurl"${dynamicPart}"abc.com'
def engine = new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine() 
paramsMap=[dynamicPart : "someDynamicPart"]
template = engine.createTemplate(url).make(paramsMap)
println template.toString()
```

Hope that helps!!

Comment: You would like to have the url as `'someurl${dynamicPart}abc.com'` without `"${dynamicPart}"`. :)